# How to register callbacks for Googles Contacts API?

Tags: callback, contacts, google-contacts-api

Instead of querying my server every x minutes for changes in my Google Contacts I rather like a certain URL to be called when a contact has been added, updated or removed either through GMail or my iPhone.

Is there a way I can register callbacks to do so?

For instance, at this point I added my GMail account to my iPhone and iMac. When I open the Contacts.APP I can see all my Gmail contacts. When I add a contact it will automatically be updated on my iPhone, on my iMac and in the GMail webinterface. However, I like to know when such an event occurs to run additional tasks through the Google Contacts API.